# First 5 words which contain substring

Tags: regex

I try to write regular expression for Mongo DB query. I need to get all posts which title first 5 words contain "foo".

E.g.

```
"It is a foo day" //true

"I try to find word foo" //false
```

Now I have `'/^((\w+\s+){,5})\bfoo/i'` but it does not work.

Comment: I was thinking in similar direction, but why 5 in regex? There should be 4. Can you test it on some strings and let us know for what strings it doesn't work.

Comment: As @AndrewLogvinov has mentioned, your second example fails because your quantifier allows 5 words and _then_ "foo".

Comment: No. This regular expression does not work at all. It does not work if I put "foo" on first place. Somewhere is mistake, but I do not understand where it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
/^(((\w+\s+){,4})foo)(?!\w)/i
```

I dropped the 5 to a 4 to only match the first 4 words along with their succeeding spaces. Since the spaces are then captured beforehand, the \b is unnecessary. Then find the foo. Afterward, we only want to match 'foo' and not 'foot' or 'food', so we make a negative lookahead for word characters.

Here's a site that shows cases that work: http://rubular.com/r/3TQiR3pvku

Hope this helps!

Comment: Works good. Thank you.
P.S. For correct working in Mongo DB I have added 0.
/^(((\w+\s+){0,4})foo)(?!\w)/i